# UITextField loses opaqueness when added to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I do an innocent addition of a textfield to a UITableViewCell and it shows up not opaque. It is illustrated in the following code: What's going on here!??

```
amtTF.opaque = YES;
NSLog(@">%@!", amtTF.opaque?@"Opaque":@"Not");
[cell.contentView addSubview:amtTF];
NSLog(@">%@!", amtTF.opaque?@"Opaque":@"Not");
```

Output:

> Opaque!
>
> Not!

Many thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Sorry, the code formatting was messed up in the original post:
    amtTF.opaque = YES;

    NSLog(@">%@!", amtTF.opaque?@"Opaque":@"Not");

    [cell.contentView addSubview:amtTF];
  
   NSLog(@">%@!", amtTF.opaque?@"Opaque":@"Not");

Comment: Obviously I don't know how to format code in SO, but hopefully you can read what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

**After** you add the UITextField then set the Opaque:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:amtTF];
 amtTF.opaque = YES;
```